# Locus equation and complex numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, locus

How to find the locus of points $z\in \mathbb{C}$ that satisfies 
$$\operatorname{arg}\left(\frac{z-z_1}{\overline{z}-z_2}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}?$$
With $z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb{C}$.

My attempt:

Let $z = x+iy, z_1=a+ib,z_2=c+id$. Substituting this into the equation, things got very messy, but I think the locus is a hyperbolic curve rotated by an angle of $\frac{\pi}{8}$, but that's not very accurate. Is there another way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Multiply the numerator and denominator of the argument of arg() by the conjugate of the denominator.  Then use $\arg\left(\dfrac{z}{a}\right)=\arg(z)$, for real $a$, to get rid of the denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply consider $$\operatorname{arg}(\frac{z-z_1}{\overline{z}-z_2})=\operatorname{arg}\{(\frac{z-z_1}{\overline{z}-z_2})\cdot (\frac {\overline{\overline{z}-z_2}}{\overline{\overline{z}-z_2}})\}$$

$$=\operatorname{arg}(\frac{z^2-(\overline{z_2}+z_1)z+\overline{z_2}z_1}{\alpha}) = \operatorname{arg}(z^2-(\overline{z_2}+z_1)z+\overline{z_2}z_1)$$

where $\alpha$ is a real number.

We can do completing the square for the numerator, so that it becomes ${z^{'}}^2 + \beta$, where $\beta$ is a complex number.

$$=\operatorname{arg}({z^{'}}^2 + \beta)$$[image]

By this diagram, we know $$ \operatorname{Re}(({z^{'}}^2 + \beta)) =\operatorname{Im}(({z^{'}}^2 + \beta))$$

Let ${z^{'}}=x+yi, \beta=a+bi$

so it satisfies $(x^2-y^2+a)=(2xy+b)$

$a,$$b$  can be known very easily, so is left for you to compute.

From the equation, it is hyperbola rotated by a certain degree.